# JPA and caching native SQL query

Tags: caching, jpa

Exist any possibility to cache native sql query in JPA ?

I found :

JPA 2.0 Cache APIs

JPA 2.0 provides a set of standard query hints to allow refreshing or bypassing the cache. The query hints are defined on the two enum classes CacheRetrieveMode and CacheStoreMode.

Query hints:

```
javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode : CacheRetrieveMode
    BYPASS : Ignore the cache, and build the object directly from the database result.
    USE : Allow the query to use the cache. If the object/data is already in the cache, the cached object/data will be used.
javax.persistence.cache.storeMode : CacheStoreMode
    BYPASS : Do not cache the database results.
    REFRESH : If the object/data is already in the cache, then refresh/replace it with the database results.
    USE : Cache the objects/data returned from the query.
```

Cache hints example

Query query = em.createQuery("Select e from Employee e");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);

but it's probably works only with not NATIVE query...

Answer (score 1):

No, the JPA cache will not work with native queries because native queries are not parsed or understood by the JPA provider - they go directly to the database.  What you might want is statement caching or query result caching, which are different concepts not covered by JPA and would be specific to your JPA provider see http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_query-results-cache.htm for info on EclipseLink's query cache (though I do not know that it works with native queries either).